# Showing certain fields of related models in Django Admin

Tags: django

I have following scenario:

There are Containers.
Each Container has Contents.

There are Consumers.
Each Consumer measures temperature of Contents

I  have Django admin page that shows:

1. Consumer
2. Container Content
3. Container Content Temperature
4. Date when Temperature was measured

I need this page to show also name of 'Parent Container' for 'Container Content'

How can I do it?

Here is content of my models.py and admin.py

in models.py:

```
class Container_Model(models.Model):
    container_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.container_name)

class Container_Content_Model(models.Model):
    container_content_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, )
    parent_container = models.ForeignKey(Container_Model, 
related_name="parent_container", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    container_content_consumers = 
models.ManyToManyField(Container_Consumer_Model)
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.container_content_name,)

class Container_Consumer_Model(models.Model):
    container_consumer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.container_consumer_name)

class Container_Content_Temperature_Model(models.Model):
    container_content = models.ForeignKey(Container_Content_Model)
    container_consumer = models.ForeignKey(Container_Consumer_Model)
    container_content_temperature = models.CharField(max_length=64, 
blank=True, null=True)
    container_content_temperature_measured_at = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.container_content_temperature)
```

in admin.py:

```
@admin.register(models.Container_Content_Temperature_Model)
class container_content_temperature_model_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
    'container_consumer',
    'container_content',
    'container_content_temperature',
    'container_content_temperature_measured_at',
    )
```

Comment: you can add related objects as shown here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/

Comment: adding inline did not work. may need something else